# How to set in a ListView text using List

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

Im starting at android development and im really interested in learn. Actually im making a android app for the administration of the one farm. I need to create a listView which show me what the administrator has buyed. So, i was trying to do set a ListView for do that.. I follow the vogella's tutorial    (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html). So, i created my class called "**NewListViewAdapter** i also created the xml file called "**newlistviewadapter**" And called in my ListFragment.

The question i already have its how to handle with List, i created a List of Compras objects and now im trying to set it to every textview in the xml file but i dont know is this is the correct way. Someone can tell me how i do that?

I was following the vogella's tutorial but they works with arrays and im trying to use the list.

Following my files:

**NewListViewAdapter**

```
package com.example.projectcandy.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.projectcandy.R;

import java.util.List;


public class NewListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List> {
private TextView tv1;
private TextView tv2;
private TextView tv3;
private TextView tv4;
private TextView tv5;
private TextView tv6;

private final Context context;
private final List values;

public NewListViewAdapter(Context context, List values) {
    super(context, R.layout.newlistview, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newlistview, parent, false);
    tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    tv3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    tv4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    tv5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

    tv1.setText((Integer) values.get(1));
    tv2.setText((Integer) values.get(1));
    tv3.setText((Integer) values.get(1));
    tv4.setText((Integer) values.get(1));
    tv5.setText((Integer) values.get(1));
    tv6.setText((Integer) values.get(1));





    return rowView;

}

}
```

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/vendedor"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/fechadecompra"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/peso_compra"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Cantidad"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/ubicacion_potrero"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="TEXTO MAS LAAAAAAAAARGO"
        android:id="@+id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView11" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView12" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView13" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Implementation in my listfragment**

```
List <Compra> compras = db.getAllCompras(id_user);


    NewListViewAdapter adapter = new NewListViewAdapter(getActivity(), compras);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

My plans about this is to show a listView if the user touch one element of the listView the user can choose if modify or delete it and for that i need the "compra" id. So thats why im showing all information and need to take the id. For modify or delete it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To handle a list item click in android you can user [OnListItemClick](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/implement-onlistitemclick-of.html) method. 
One scenario of handling the modify and or delete option would be to have something like an alert dialog pop up with the options. You can also decide to take the user to another activity and handle modification and deletion of that object there. Whatever works best for you.

Comment: ok, thanks. But how about use list of one object? i want to take the id from a object of that list